# Computer encountered critical error and started cleanly instead of resuming after hibernation

Tags: windows-10, crash, shutdown, hibernate

I had a problem with my computer - last night I hibernated it, which I assume completed fine, as it turned off but I didn't monitor it closely or anything. I am running Windows 10 Pro.

Today when I turned it on, it started as if it was shutdown, instead of continuing from he point at which it was hibernated. Also, not sure if this matters but my monitor was turned off and I don't remember turning it off.

Not that it matters for hibernation but the power hasn't gone out at any point from last night to today, I have other machines running that would make me 100% notice if it did.

I woke my computer today at around 11:25 and in my EventViewer there is a single critical event that occurred at 11:26:39, which is:

`The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.`

Mind you no critical event was recorded at the time of hibernation. In fact this is the only critical event for the last 7 days.

The only error events around the time of hibernation and startup are the following error:

`The server Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2020.20070.10002.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe!App.AppXy9rh3t8m2jfpvhhxp6y2ksgeq77vymbq.mca did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.`

That is the last event right before hibernation and then again today at 11:25:33.

These are the following events:

(aforementioned critical)

11:26:39 - Critical - `The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.`

11:26:42 - Error - `The previous system shutdown at 11:25:34 AM on ‎3/‎09/‎2020 was unexpected.`

11:26:42 - Error - `Audit events have been dropped by the transport.  0`

11:26:45 - Error - `The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was: 0x0000007e (0xffffffffc0000005, 0xfffff80665165c8b, 0xffffd20d1d19bc38, 0xffffd20d1d19b470). A dump was saved in: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 125794f2-422f-4a30-b392-6b9241d1d205.`

I know normally this shouldn't be such a big deal, but:

1. I've never had a computer do a clean start after hibernation, instead of resuming.

2. Much more bizarrely - my Vivaldi web browser now looses all cookies after restarting the computer. It has default settings to allow cookies and keep browsing data for three months. Never had such a problem with it before.

Potential cause of the problem:

Since I fiddled with disabling some services only to find out Windows 10 needs just about every little pesky annoyance to work properly, I used this script/command to restore all my services to defaults: https://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/138011-restore-windows-services-default-startup-settings.html

I saved the commands to a *.bat file and ran it. I didn't restart after that.

EDIT: Computer just hibernated fine.

EDIT MKII: [System Logs](https://we.tl/t-6kpXQpV9k1)

Comment: I suggest you update BIOS and Power Driver if one and then see if Hibernation works. Be careful about making registry changes "just to see"